# Prevent the IBAction of a UIButton from being executed if the button is being repeatedly tapped

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uibutton

I have a `UIButton` that executes networking code upon clicking. The networking code updates a record on the server. Is there a way that I can prevent this networking code from being executed if the button is being repeatedly tapped, as this would just be a waste of resources?

Answer (score 5):

In the `IBAction`, change the button's `isUserInteractionEnabled` property to `false` and set it back to `true` when the network request finishes execution.

Comment: Thats a suitable answer in most cases, but doesn't really suit my needs. Picture a like button that you can flick on and off, I don't want to disable it. Actually I think a timer would be a good idea so that the code is called like a second after being pressed sort of thing.

Comment: Without being more precise in your question, you can't get an exact answer. Why would you want to push a like button several times? A timer is definitely a bad idea. Imagine if you have really bad connection, so a single request takes like 30sec, how would a timer of 1sec help?

Answer (score 1):

You can add a flag in your class or use the request object to determine if the app is currently sending

Before starting the send change the value to true and after you finish set it back to false

in this way you can use the same button as a cancel button.
or you can show an alert about the sending state

here is a sample:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

   var isSending = false

   @IBAction func sendTouched(_ sender: UIButton) {

      guard !isSending else { return }

      send()
   }

   func send() {

      isSending = true

      // send data to server

   }

   // call this after you finish sending
   func notifyFinished() {

      isSending = false
   }
}
```